# @Html.DisplayFor() will not show client side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, displayfor

I am developing in MVC 4 and i would like to have a read only text box. I decided to use @Html.DisplayFor but i cant get it to show on client side?

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GoodsModel.SerialNumber) <label id ="VGoodsSerialNumber" style="color: #FF0000;"/>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GoodsModel.SerialNumber)
    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.GoodsModel.SerialNumber, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })*@
</div>
```

Then when i run i can't find it?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, still does not render the EditorFor as read only.

Comment: Do you have template for type of your model?

Answer (score 2):

Html.EditorFor does not have an htmlAttributes parameter. You need to use Html.TextBoxFor if you want to pass html attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GoodsModel.SerialNumber, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Also, use either disabled or readonly. When the input is disabled, its value will not be posted to the server when submitting the form. The readonly input will still be posted, but its value cannot be changed by the user.